# Numpy applying a time interval sequence to a multidimensional ndarray (such as coordinates)

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation, numpy-ndarray

EDIT: added prefix / suffix value to interval arrays to make them the same length as their corresponding data arrays, as per @user1319128 's suggestion and indeed interp does the job.  For sure his solution was workable and good.  I just couldn't see it because I was tired and stupid.

I am sure this is a fairly mundane application, but so I have failed to find or come up with a way to do this without doing it outside of numpy.  Maybe my brain just needs a rest, anyway here is the problem with example and solution requirements.

So I have to arrays with different lengths and I want to apply common time intervals between them to these arrays, so that that the result is I have versions of these arrays that are all the same length and their values relate to each other at the same row (if that makes sense).  In the example below I have named this functionality "apply_timeintervals_to_array".  The example code:

```
import numpy as np
from colorsys import hsv_to_rgb

num_xy = 20
num_colors = 12

#xy = np.random.rand(num_xy, 2) * 1080
xy = np.array([[ 687.32758344,  956.05651214],
               [ 226.97671414,  698.48071588],
               [ 648.59878864,  175.4882185 ],
               [ 859.56600997,  487.25205922],
               [ 794.43015178,   16.46114312],
               [ 884.7166732 ,  634.59100322],
               [ 878.94218682,  835.12886098],
               [ 965.47135726,  542.09202328],
               [ 114.61867445,  601.74092126],
               [ 134.02663822,  334.27221884],
               [ 940.6589034 ,  245.43354493],
               [ 285.87902276,  550.32600784],
               [ 785.00104142,  993.19960822],
               [1040.49576307,  486.24009511],
               [ 165.59409198,  156.79786175],
               [1043.54280058,  313.09073855],
               [ 645.62878826,  100.81909068],
               [ 625.78003257,  252.17917611],
               [1056.77009875,  793.02218098],
               [   2.93152052,  596.9795026 ]])
xy_deltas = np.sum((xy[1:] - xy[:-1])**2, axis=-1)
xy_ti = np.concatenate(([0.0],
                        (xy_deltas) / np.sum(xy_deltas)))

colors_ti = np.concatenate((np.linspace(0, 1, num_colors),
                           [1.0]))

common_ti = np.unique(np.sort(np.concatenate((xy_ti,
                                              colors_ti))))

common_colors = (np.array(tuple(hsv_to_rgb(t, 0.9, 0.9) for t
                                in np.concatenate(([0.0],
                                                   common_ti,
                                                   [1.0]))))
                 * 255).astype(int)[1:-1]
common_xy = apply_timeintervals_to_array(common_ti, xy)
```

So one could then use the common arrays for additional computations or for rendering.

The question is what could accomplish the "apply_timeintervals_to_array" functionality, or alternatively a better way to generate the same data.

I hope this is clear enough, let me know if it isn't.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Question is not clear . Do you mean , you would like to resample 2 time series  of different lengths , so that they represent data at same time ?

Comment: @user1319128 rather apply a common time series to arrays of different lengths.  Or more specifically the end result should be common time scale with common data.

Comment: In your example code,  the two columns of `xy` array are of same length. It leads to confusion. Do they belong to different time stamps ? and you would like to extract / interpolate data at common time stamps ?

Comment: @user1319128 Yes, because it is one array, the two arrays are colors and xy, specifically.  More clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think , `numpy.interp` should meet your expectations.For example, If a have an 2d array of length 20 , and would like to interpolate at different `common_ti` values ,whose length is 30 , the code would be as follows.

```
xy = np.arange(0,400,10).reshape(20,2)
xy_ti = np.arange(20)/19
common_ti = np.linspace(0,1,30)
x=np.interp(common_ti,xy_ti,xy[:,0]) # interpolate the first column
y=np.interp(common_ti,xy_ti,xy[:,1]) #interpolate the second column
```

Comment: I had to use , different arrays , because, your `xy_ti`is of length 19 , however, `xy` is of length 20. Make sure `xy_ti`and length of `xy` match. `common_ti` length can be different.